# Solution to fix the Java Virtual Machine Hotspot Error?

Tags: java, swing, virtual-machine

I am facing a HotSpot Virtual Machine error with the following details-

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0bfc58d5, pid=5412, tid=5284    
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.5.0_10-b03 mixed mode)
Problematic frame:
C  [ExtractDetails.dll+0x158d5]
An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid5412.log    
[Current thread (0x0b0349c0):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=5284]
```

The error occurs only for a particular data from a file which the program is trying to read and this is causing it to crash.

Is there any solution to fix this error or atleast a way to find out where exactly it is failing. 
I tried increasing the Java Virtual Machine Memory from the Control Panel by setting the Runtime Parameters to -Xmx4G but still facing the same issue.

Geeks any idea to fix this ? 
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using another VM, to see if you still hit the same bug (e.g. it's not from the VM itself, but from the code)?

Comment: Yes Romain. I used another VM but I still see the same kind of error this time: A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: # # EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x045758d5, pid=3664, tid=2748 # # JRE version: 6.0_18-b05 # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.0-b12 mixed mode windows-x86 ) # Problematic frame: # C [ExtractDetails.dll+0x158d5]

Answer (score 4):

Most likely this is a bug in that ExtractDetails.dll that you are using. In that case there is nothing you can do to fix this at the java side.

Comment: Mark, how can I detect where in the ExtractDetails.dll it is crashing coz I am using a native code in my Java class.

Comment: You can attach the debugger of your JNI library to the java.exe process and use breakpoints and other debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest try would be to update the user Java runtime to a more current version.

Even if you want/have to stay in the 1.5 /J2SE 5 branch your version 1.5.0_10-b03 is heavily outdated. The last published version of Java 1.5 is 1.5.0_22.

But I would recommend to update to the most recent version of Java 1.6 - if your application has no problem with that. Usually Java programs are backward compatible.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I have upgraded the Java version now to 1.6 But still facing the same kind of error -A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: # # EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x045758d5, pid=3664, tid=2748 # # JRE version: 6.0_18-b05 # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.0-b12 mixed mode windows-x86 ) # Problematic frame: # C [ExtractDetails.dll+0x158d5]